# angularjs html5mode not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

If I don't use the html5mode, everything works fine. But when I activate it I keep getting 404  error on every request.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
        .state('404', {
            url: '/404',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: '404.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

and I use the ui-route state provider :

```
$stateProvider.state('mandates', {
            url: '/domiciliations/mandats',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'directDebit/views/mandates.html',
                    controller: 'mandates.ctrl',
                },
                'menu-action': {
                    templateUrl: 'directDebit/views/menu/menu.mandates.html',
                    controller: 'menu.mandates.ctrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

So if I try to access mydomain/app/domiciliations/mandats, I get a 404. If I don't use html5 mode, then requesting mydomain/app/#/domiciliations/mandats.

Any idea what I should change ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure your server is setup to redirect all requests to your index/app. What server are you running?

Comment: IIS. So switching to html5 mode is not enough, right ?  What would the redirection look like in the above example ?

Comment: Correct. You will need to modify your web.config to redirect for you.

Comment: all is working fine now, I've done the url rewriting on the server side.

Comment: I have the same problem in nginx and nothing seems to work. 
base url is set, nginx is set, html5mode(true) is set, but it keeps giving out 404 errors when I refresh. If I go to base page, I can navigate, but I can no longer navigate to absolute URLs in the website.